# Angular forEach with comparison from json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, foreach

So I have an input field which fetches data from lets say json1.
On submit, I want that input value to be compared to data from json2 and do different stuff depending on the outcome, but I can't wrap my head around it since I can't break the forEach. My code is executing but winds through it all instead of stoping on corresponding if statement.

I've seen a couple of threads talking about using for-loop instead but no luck there either. Any ideas?

I would like something like this:

```
$scope.superButton = function() {
$http.get(superUrl)
    .then(function(res) {

        angular.forEach(res.data, function(item) {
            // If supertag exists, add to it
            if ($scope.id == item.tag.tag_id) {
                console.log('yay, tag is now supertag');

                $http({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: superUrl,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: {
                        'title': $scope.title,
                        'subtitle': $scope.subtitle,
                        'tag': {
                            'title': $scope.selected,
                            'tag_id': $scope.id
                        }
                    }
                }).then(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
                    console.log('added EXISTING supertag:' + data.statusText);

                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err.data.message);
                });
            }
            // If supertag doesn't exist, create it
            else if ($scope.id != item.tag.tag_id) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: superUrl,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: {
                        'title': $scope.title,
                        'subtitle': $scope.subtitle,
                        'tag': {
                            'title': $scope.selected,
                            'tag_id': $scope.id
                        }
                    }
                }).then(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
                    console.log('added NEW supertag: ' + data.statusText);

                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err.data.message);
                });
            }
            // If
            else {
                console.log('no tags');
            }
        });
    });
```

};

Comment: Have you make `console.log(res.data)`? Is getting the right data response?

Comment: say you have 100 items in your `res.data`. Are you going to send 100 http requests? Because your code will send `$http` regardless the results have super tags or not. `exists` and `doesn't exists` is binary, and hence your last `if` will not get executed, unless I missed out something?

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Yes, it logs correct, just removed a bunch of console.logs before I pasted the code.

Comment: @CozyAzure I get your point, what I want to do is for it to check if input (from JSON1 = tags) already IS a supertag (at JSON2 = supertags), otherwise create it (in JSON2). Not too familiar with these kind of projects, any ideas of how I should improve/go further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to validate if `$http.get()` response contains a `supertag`:

```
$scope.superButton = function() {
    $http.get(superUrl)
        .then(function(res) {
            var len = res.data.filter(function(item) {
                    return $scope.id === item.tag.tag_id;
                }).length,
                method = (len) ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
                segmentUrl = (len) ? '/' + $scope.id : '',
                msg = (len) ? 'EXISTING supertag: ' : 'NEW supertag: ';

            $http({
                    method: method,
                    url: superUrl + segmentUrl,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: {
                        'title': $scope.title,
                        'subtitle': $scope.subtitle,
                        'tag': {
                            'title': $scope.selected,
                            'tag_id': $scope.id
                        }
                    }
                })
                .then(function(data, status, headers, config, statusText) {
                    console.log(msg + data.statusText);
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err.data.message);
                });
        });
};
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! That seems to work just fine! Now I just need to figure out why Swagger doesn't want my PUT directive. Marking as solved! :)

Comment: Good to help.. You have to see now if you have to change the URL passing a parameter for the `PUT` request

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, POST only needs url/supertag while PUT needs url/supertag/{tag_id}

Comment: I have added a variable `segmentUrl` to handle the for PUT `url/supertag/{tag_id}`

Comment: Tried another approach but your work looked much better. :D Now I get POST error when I try to update the input, don't know if it's a Swagger issue  or on my side, "Duplicate key value violates unique constraint 'supertags_tag_id_idx'". Swagger is totally new to me..

Comment: Removing a forEach earlier in the code seems to have done it, now I can POST and PUT as I'd like! Huge thank you for your help!